# I am using ffmpeg to stream a h264 encoded avi file to a player and the player supports only packetization mode 0

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to stream a h264 encoded avi file to a player and 
the player supports only packetization mode 0 ( single NAL unit mode 
). But ffmpeg always uses packetization mode 1 and sends FU-A nal unit 
type, the player does not play the video on receiving a fu-a nal type 
payload. It just displays a blank screen. I understand non-interleaved 
mode supports both single NAL unit types (1-23) and fua, but how to 
can I force ffmpeg to use only single nal unit type mode? Can some one 
help me?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean H264 over RTP here. FFmpeg's RTP muxer can be forced to use mode 0 by using flag `-rtpflags h264_mode0`; though if you are seeing FU-A type (28) then chances are some NAL units can't fit single RTP packet and mode0 won't work.